# Java: Replace all non-digit symbols except symbol "+" on the first position

Tags: java, regex, replaceall

I`d like to format inputed strings over such rule: replace all non-digit symbols except first position in the string: it should be only digit or symbol '+'.

I use regexp functionality

```
private static final String REGEXP_NOT_DIGITS = "[^\\+0-9]";

String result = sample.replaceAll(REGEXP_NOT_DIGITS, "");
```

But the result of this replacement is string with digits and '+' symbols at any position.
Please, help me to clarify my condition that I would replace all '+' symbol except only 1 position in the line.

Edit.  Right now output is:

> sample[0] sample = 0123456789; result = 0123456789              expected:0123456789
>
> sample[1] sample = +380+380+380+; result = +380+380+380+        expected:+380380380
>
> sample[2] sample = dd0 11 22 33 44 55; result = 01122334455     expected:01122334455
>
> sample[3] sample = +380-456(789); result = +380456789           expected:+380456789
>
> sample[4] sample = d3+580 456 789; result = 3+580456789         expected:3580456789
>
> sample[5] sample =  +380456789; result = +380456789             expected:+380456789

Everything is Ok except having symbol '+' inside string

Comment: provide an example along with expected output..

Comment: Can you add some sample input and output strings.

Comment: @Alex could you add the expected output for each  sample?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use:

```
String result = sample.replaceAll("(?!^)\\+|[^+\\d]+", "");
```

#### [RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pK3hC1/2)

`(?!^)\\+` is a negative lookahead that will match `+` everywhere except at line start.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the below regex,

```
(?!^\\+)\\D
```

Matches any non-digit character except the `+` symbol which was at the start.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/iL8wR1/2)

```
String result = sample.replaceAll("(?!^\\+)\\D", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

`"^[^\\d+]|\\D"`

Comment: I'm not sure what the left side is supposed to mean. But the right side would match **all** non-digits in the string.

Comment: @Robert if you know the op needs then edit the above question.

Comment: Right, that's what we need, isn't it? The left side means neither a digit nor a plus sign in the beginning of the line.

Comment: I just mean that `"\\D"` also matches a plus sign in the beginning of the line. I am under the assumption that this isn't intended. You also added it in the list of things not to match at the beginning `"^[^\\d+]"`.

Comment: Not so good. First "+" lost...      sample[0] sample = 0123456789; result = 0123456789
sample[1] sample = +380+380+380+; result = 380380380
sample[2] sample = dd0 11 22 33 44 55; result = 01122334455
sample[3] sample = +380-456(789); result = 380456789
sample[4] sample = d3+580 456 789; result = 3580456789
sample[5] sample =  +380456789; result = 380456789